# Use of cross-platform C++ dynamic library from C# Uno project

Tags: c#, c++, cross-platform, pinvoke, uno-platform

I'm working on the port of the C# UWP project to Uno-Platform. The original project references a lot of logic from C++ DLLs. The interface between C# and C++ library is rather big to write PInvoke wrappers manually.

Is there any complete solution to automate the calling of C++ library methods from .NET?

Answer (score 0):

The Uno Platform does not provide anything specific for this type of scenarios, and relies on what .NET already provides (P/Invoke in this case).

You may want to take a look at https://github.com/EgorBo/CppPinvokeGenerator or https://github.com/xoofx/CppAst.NET to generate C# from the C++ code.